# If condition for Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create different rules based on the environment

for the resource

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule"

if env == prod 
   then 
   action {
    type = "redirect"

```
redirect {
  host = "${var.}"
  path = "/path"
  port = "443"
  protocol = "HTTPS"
  status_code = "HTTP_302"
}
```

else 
     action {
    type = "fixed-response"

```
fixed_response {
  content_type = "path"
  status_code  = 503
  message_body = "${data.template_file.xxx_html.rendered}"
}
```

}

how can I achieve something like this using terraform ?

Comment: Can you provide the full versipons of the resource you're creating? Are `redirect` and `fixed_response` blocks within that resouce?

Answer (score 2):

The general approach in `terraform` is to use resource `count` as an if statement to create or not the resource in that scenario.

You can set the count of the `aws_lb_listener_rule` resource that will hold the `redirect` to a value of `1` only if the `environment` variable is set to `prod`.

The following example has the effect you desire.

```
resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "production_redirect_listener" {
  # Create this rule only if the environment variable is set to production
  count = var.environment == "prod" ? 1 : 0

  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.arn
  action {
    type = "redirect"

    redirect {
      host = var.hostname
      path = "/path"
      port = "443"
      protocol = "HTTPS"
      status_code = "HTTP_302"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener_rule" "generic_fixed_response" {
  # If the environment variable is set to production do NOT create this rule
  count = var.environment == "prod" ? 0 : 1

  listener_arn = aws_lb_listener.arn
  action {
    type = "fixed-response"

    fixed_response {
      content_type = "path"
      status_code  = 503
      message_body = data.template_file.xxx_html.rendered
    }
  }
}
```